# Sorting strings with punctuation using Intl.Collator is inconsistent across browsers

Tags: javascript, sorting, collation

In my project the sorting of data is done using javascript. but we ran into a problem where the strings with hyphen (-) are not sorted consistently across browsers (mainly IE, Chrome, Firefox).We use Intl.Collator as comparer but found out that the comparer has a different behavior across browsers when it comes to punctuation and symbols, mainly hyphen (-).

Here's a sample code

```js
window.strings = ko.observableArray([ "con", "coop", "co-op", "co&op", "co!op"]);
var Collator = new Intl.Collator("en-u-kn");

strings.sort(Collator.compare);

ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach:strings">
   <li data-bind="text:$data"></li>
</ul>
```

In chrome, it places the strings with symbols first. In IE11, it places the "co-op" after "coop".

Is there a locale or option in Intl.Collator so that the symbols/punctuations are consistently sorted between browsers?